# can objects be marked not to be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I don't know too much about the JavaScript garbage collector, just that it attempts to manage references so that unreferenced objects can be periodically purged from memory.  I was thinking about something that I thought might improve performance if it was feasible by the language implementers.

It would go something like this.  In a file add a line:

```
"no gc";
```

This is similar to the `use strict` setting.  It would mark everything defined in the file as not for garbage collection.  I'm thinking this would be used in libraries like jQuery and underscore.  All of the helper methods would be marked and stored in a separate area of memory that is not managed by the GC.

While I know this might end up keeping around stuff that is not ever used; it would at least isolate it from periodic GC process.  So while we perhaps gobble up some extra memory, we at least lighten the load of GC processing.

I apologize for the naivety of this suggestion as I have never implemented GC.  I am just wondering if this idea is feasible or if JavaScript somehow does this already.

Comment: I think this could increase "fragmentation" - memory that would have been reused (by GC) is now kept for useless stuff...

Comment: my 2 cents: the GC is fairly well optimized, doesn't eat much CPU, so it's not worth adding such a feature...

Comment: There's the `"use asm";` declarative, but that's only in Firefox right now, and requires that you write (or generate) code specifically for asm.js. However it doesn't use the garbage collector AFAIK.  Anyway, this is probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to keep them as cache then you have global scope.

In browser global scope is window,

hence consider if you dont want object X to never get garbage collected then simply you can write

```
window.nogc = X;
```

since window which is global scoped ,will be never garbage collected so its child references also wont be garbage colleted until we explicitly make it.

Comment: that's how (for example) jQuery stays in memory... read the question again, he was asking about something else...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: something else? What else? I upvoted this answer as I believe this answers the question.

Comment: as far as i understand he is talking about a way to make a pool of objects in the heap which should never be garbage collected.
But since Javascript already provides such method there is no need for any keyword,as far as "use strict" is considered it was added not to break code before ECMAScript 5

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: you are not helping others to learn from you. In fact, I find your comment offensive. I am not sure if this was your intention.

Comment: he doesn't want the GC to *spend time* figuring out whether that object *could be* freed. that's how I understood it. read the Q again (I know I already said this but I'm not sure you did).

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Karoly is right. The question is about relieving the garbage collector of the task of managing certain objects. If the object is global, it still needs to be managed by the GC because it can't know when/if it will be released.

Comment: @cookiemonster: assuming that gc starts from the root and you attach non-collectable objects to the root, gc doesn't have much to do to determine that such objects are not meant to be collected. Seems like a good alternative to an "if" that you would need anyway.

Comment: @cookiemonster : if you keep your your non garbage collectible objects nearer to root(distance between root to leaf is less),very less work is required by GC to determine if the collection needs to be triggered or not.

Comment: I'm not sure why you guys telling him this... all we wanted to say that this answer doesn't address the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection only runs when the thread is free. Nothing would be saved because GC only occurs when the system isn't busy.

So no, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that an object does not get collected by referencing it from a GC root, but not that it doesn't get processed by the GC.

The reason is that GC in JS VMs is usually implemented via Mark-and-Sweep, or a method that is functionally equivalent. The basic premise is that the GC goes through a cycle that goes like this:

1. The GC marks all objects in the heap as being "potentially available for release". This is usually done by a flag toggle which changes the *interpretation* of the existing marks on objects from meaning "need to keep" to "safe to release". So no actual iteration over the objects occurs at this stage. Telling the GC to "not mark" certain objects would actually require extra operations, not less.
2. The GC starts at the GC roots, and traverse through the reference tree, changing the mark of objects from "safe to release" to "need to keep". This is the "Mark" phase. GC roots can be global objects, the currently executing stack, pending callbacks on the event loop, etc. The tree-traversal itself can be done in various way as well, with DFS being the simplest.
3. The GC goes over all objects in the heap, and removes any that is still marked "safe to release". This is the "Sweep" phase. Many optimizations exist in this phase, which allows the GC to free memory used by a group of objects in a single operation. Nevertheless, this requires at least some level of iteration, over groups of objects, if not over objects themselves.

Now here's the issue with setting a "non-GC" arena: Suppose that an object in your "non-GC" arena was to reference a regular object. During the "Mark" phase, if that object is not marked, it would be released. That means that all of your "non-collectible" objects need to be GC roots in order to "keep" regular objects to which they refer. And being a GC root offers no performance advantage over being directly referenced by a GC root. Both must equally participate in the "Mark" phase.

The only alternative is for your non-collectible object to not be able to strongly reference collectible objects at all. This can be achieved by having your own binary heap, rather than using native JS objects. The binary data would not be interpreted as references, and the heap object would finish its marking phase in a single operation. This is what asm.js does: It preallocates a large array to act as its internal heap. To the VM, the entire array counts as one big object, and therefore no garbage collection is done on any data structures that are encoded within it. Using this method does have the flaw that you need to encode all of your objects and data structures into the heap's binary format, and decode them when you want to use them. When working with asm.js, this is handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript if you want to kill a object, you have to delete all the references.
let's say we have a object like this:

```
var myobj={ obj : {} };
```

and we want to GC the obj object, we have to do this:

```
myobj["obj"] = null;
delete myobj["obj"];
```

but if you define another variable referenced to that object, it won't be killed with those line. for instance if you do:

```
var obj = myobj.obj;
```

if you really want to delete the object, you have do the same for this variable:

```
obj  = null;
delete obj;
```

then if there is no reference it would be killed.
in other word if you want to prevent your object from GC, create a reference some where and keep it private.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but `delete` was necessary.  `myobj["obj"] = null` should suffice by itself assuming it used to refer to some object.